# Why there are NAs generated form ksmooth in R?

Tags: r, na, smoothing

Why there are NAs generated form `ksmooth` in R?

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sort(rnorm(1000,0,2))
e <- rnorm(1000)
y <- x + e
ks <- ksmooth(x,y,kernel='normal')
ks$y[c(944,945)]
[1] NA NA
```

Answer (score 4):

Because the default bandwidth is 0.5 and those two points occur at x values that are more than 0.5 from any other. They both occur at around 6.8 I believe.

```
plot(x,y)
lines(ks,col = "blue")
```

[image]

If you increase the bandwidth, you should remove the `NA`s.

Comment: Thank you! You are right. I knew it is because of the bandwidth, but varified it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the problem, thanks to @joran.

```
> min(abs(x - ks$x[944]))
[1] 0.7446518
> min(abs(x - ks$x[945]))
[1] 0.7507665
```

We can see that the nearest points are further than the default bandwidth 0.5.